# PagewiseLoadController setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter_pagewise dependency

```
class _TagImagesScreenState extends State<TagImagesScreenState> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          ...,
          PageWiseMemeList(widget.tag)
        ],
      ),
     );
```

where PageWiseMemeList is implemented in the following way:

```
class PageWiseMemeList extends StatelessWidget {
  final MemeTag tag;

  PageWiseMemeList(this.tag);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const int PAGESIZE = 10;
    return Expanded(
      child: PagewiseGridView.count(
        pageSize: PAGESIZE,
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
        childAspectRatio: 0.555,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        itemBuilder: (context, entry, index) =>
            _buildMemeGridItem(context, entry),
        pageFuture: (pageIndex) =>
            this.tag.getMemeFilesFuture(pageIndex * PAGESIZE, PAGESIZE),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and finally _buildMemeGridItem is implemented

```
  Widget _buildMemeGridItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      MemeFile meme = MemeFile.fromMap(document.data, document.documentID);

      return Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: () {
            MemeShare().shareFile(meme);
          },
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/image_view',
                arguments: ImageViewerArguments(meme));
          },
          child: FadeInImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/placeholder.jpg'),
            image: CacheImage(meme.getGsPath()),
          ),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when I try to execute this code I always get the following error:

```
════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for PagewiseLoadController<dynamic>:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This PagewiseGridView<dynamic> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: PagewiseGridView<dynamic>
  state: PagewiseState<dynamic>#0fea7
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: SliverGrid
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate#1454c(estimated child count: 1)
  renderObject: RenderSliverGrid#bc245 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3896:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3911:6)
#2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1168:14)
#3      PagewiseState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_pagewise/flutter_pagewise.dart:201:39)
#4      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:206:21)
...
The PagewiseLoadController<dynamic> sending notification was: Instance of 'PagewiseLoadController<dynamic>'
```

When I try to debug I found that 
PagewiseState has the following code in initState()

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.pageLoadController == null) {
      this._controller = PagewiseLoadController<T>(
          pageFuture: widget.pageFuture, pageSize: widget.pageSize);
    }

    this._effectiveController.init();

    this._controllerListener = (() => setState(() {}));

    this._effectiveController.addListener(this._controllerListener);
  }
```

Not sure if that's the issue, but may be it can help, line 201 is:
`this._controllerListener = (() => setState(() {}));`

Comment: `flutter_pagewise.dart:201:39` - what is in that file, line 201, column 39?

Comment: It's a flutter component that I've used in my project: https://github.com/AbdulRahmanAlHamali/flutter_pagewise/blob/master/lib/flutter_pagewise.dart

Comment: this._controllerListener = (() => setState(() {}))